# First Stored procedure with parameter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

this is my query in MySQL on table `tbl_T367`

```
mysql> SELECT
    oID,
    xName
FROM
    `tbl_T367`
WHERE
    oID IN ('2')
AND xName IN ('T367');

+-----+-------+
| oID | xName |
+-----+-------+
|   2 | T367  |
+-----+-------+
1 row in set
```

i need create mysql stored procedure for the same output like above

my code below

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_sqrt$$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_sqrt(xName char(4), oID INT (11))
BEGIN

DECLARE xNamenew CHAR (4);
DECLARE IDnew INT (11);

SET @xNamenew = xName;
SET @IDnew = oID;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tbl_', @xNamenew, 
                ' WHERE oID IN (' + @IDnew + ') AND xName IN (' + @xNamenew + ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;

END

DELIMITER ;
```

but the result

`Procedure execution failed
1146 - Table 'tbl_T3672' doesn't exist`

why was the value of the second variable added to the table name?

```
mysql> SELECT
    oID,
    xName
FROM
    `tbl_T3672`
WHERE
    oID IN ('2')
AND xName IN ('T367');
1146 - Table 'tbl_t3672' doesn't exist
mysql>
```

how to do resolve this?

**update**

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tbl_', @xNamenew, 
                ' WHERE oID IN (' , @IDnew , ') AND xName IN (' , @xNamenew ,')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;

Procedure execution failed
1054 - Unknown column 'T367' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: It's just a typo. You wrote several `+` instead of `, `.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for help, please see **update** in my question

Comment: @UncleVince in your `my_sqrt` stored procedure, you are calling the same stored procedure again. Is that your intent? It seems like you want a stored procedure to which you can send T367 and 2 as the parameters and it should execute a query for you and produced results, correct?

Comment: @zedfoxus So sorry, error in copy paste. I've correct the stored procedure in question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues (I haven't reviewed the original procedure thoroughly):

- MySQL doesn't have a string concatenation operator. `+` is the [addition operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) thus your strings will be cast to numbers and added.
- You're inflicting yourself SQL injection. Literal strings in SQL must be single-quoted, but that isn't something you need to take care yourself.
- You're invoking the procedure from itself.
- You are missing the ending delimiter.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_sqrt;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sqrt(xName char(4), oID INT (11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE xNamenew CHAR (4);
    DECLARE IDnew INT (11);

    SET @xNamenew = xName;
    SET @IDnew = oID;

    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tbl_', @xNamenew, 
                    ' WHERE oID = ? AND xName = ?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @IDnew, @xNamenew;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL my_sqrt('T367', '2');
```

Comment: Note that `xNamenew` and `@xNamenew` are two different variables (and variable types). Variables defined with `DECLARE` are local variables and `@` variables are user defined variables. In the example `xNamenew` and `IDnew` variables are never used and have no value (are NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Alvaro's answer shows you how to use parameterized queries to reduce the chances of injection. This procedure below is just for educational purposes to show you the difference between what you had and how close you were to getting it right.

There are some variables you didn't need. You can take the input and create a concatenated string. Since you would send '2', it may not be concatenated with the single quotes. So, you have to include single quotes in the concatenation like shown below.

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists my_sqrt$$

create procedure my_sqrt(xName varchar(10), oID varchar(10))
begin

    set @s = concat(
        "select * from tbl_", xName,
        " where oID in ('", oID, "')",
        " and xName in ('", xName, "')"
    );

    prepare stmt from @s;
    execute stmt;

end$$

delimiter ;
```

Again, this is for educational purposes. Use Alvaro's method.